# Is there a relationship between these variables?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have 10 independent variables and 1 dependent variable. I need to know if independent variables have a relationship with my dependent variable. I'm performing a multiple regression, and I have the following results:

My ${R}^2$ is too small (.3), even with the full model. Is that enough to say that there's no relationship between my variables? If not, how can I give reasons to accept or reject that hypothesis? I'm working with R.

Comment: Show us your code and if possible post `dput(yourdata)`. What problem domain are you working in? In some cases an r-squared of .3 is not bad, or some other error metric is more applicable.

Comment: I don't have my code now, but  I think my model is fine. ( I've checked the assumptions)
My question is in general. I mean I'm looking for something that let me say "Noup, there's no relationship between the 10 ${X}_{i}$ and my $Y$" (Using R)

Comment: It's possible to have non-zero R2 for a non-linear model. Your information is not sufficient to say whether the variables are linear or not. You need the whole model summary statistics.